# jQuery: Call function periodically while click is held

Tags: jquery

When an element is clicked, I want to call a function every n seconds until the mouse button is released.

How should I do this?

EDIT:

```
    var interval,
        i = 0;

    $("a").on("mousedown", function(){
           interval = setInterval(function(){ $(".results").append(i++); }, 250);
    });

    $(document.body).on("mouseup", function(){
           clearInterval(interval)
    });​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/BDSUZ/

Answer (score 3):

Call `setInterval` in the `mousedown` handler, then call `clearInterval` in `mouseup`.